# Tangent cone on polyhedral spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, polyhedra

Let $X$ be an n-dimensional polyhedral space with, say, $n\geq 3.$ Let also $p\in X$ be a vertex on a triangulation $\tau$ of $X,$ so a vertex on the polyhedral space.

The tangent cone (as a metric space) of $X$ at $p$ is given by the limit $$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} (X,\lambda d_X, p),$$ where $d_X$ is the distance on $X.$ Lebedeva and Petrunin (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.6670.pdf) have shown that a compact length space $X$ is polyhedral if and only if a neighbourhood of each point on $X$ admits an open isometric embedding to a Euclidean cone which sends said point to the tip of the point. I am trying to figure out what the cone on a vertex point would be.

Say, in particular, that $n=3.$ So we have that the vertex point $p\in X$ is where 3 edges meet. Any intuition for how the cone should look like? In particular, the space of directions or the link of this cone.

Comment: The question is unclear, but anyway: Consider $\varepsilon$-sphere around the point rescaled by $\tfrac1\varepsilon$. Equip it with the induced intrinsic metric; you get a spherical polyhedral space. It is the almost space of direction --- you need modify it slightly: if distance between points is $>\pi$, then change it to $\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear, but I think you mean that $p$ is the vertex of a simplex in the triangulation of $X$. In that case, take all the simplices containing $p$, viewed as simplices embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, and note how they are glued together inside $X$. Now take the *cone* over each simplex *based at* $p$; this is set of all geodesic rays emanating from $p$ which pass through another point of the simplex. This gives you a bunch of convex cones in $\mathbb R^3$, which you now glue together using the same gluing scheme as for the original simplices. The resulting space is the Euclidean cone you want—it is the *tangent cone* of $X$ at $p$, denoted by $T_pX$.

The unit sphere about $p$ in $T_pX$, equipped with its intrinsic metric, is what I would call the *link* of $p$ in $X$, but I don't know how standard this is. To get the space of directions, take the link as I just defined it, and (as suggested by Anton) replace any distance greater than $\pi$ by $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still trying to build some intuition for polyhedral spaces, so I apologise if the question wasn't that clear. Thanks anyway!